# Creating Android Apps with MongoDB

Tags: android, mongodb

How can I create an android app that uses a mongoDB database locally i.e. Clients can make CRUD operations without connecting to a server. Sort of how SQLite is used, except this time I wanna use mongoDB.

I have checked around and what seems to be my most suitable option is using mongodb java driver, but the problem is how and what am I connecting the mongoClient to? Do I have to sort of start a server or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using firebase or realm or something that comes with better native mobile support. Couchbase Mobile might be of interest too, but I have not used it. https://developer.couchbase.com/mobile